# Visual or Geometric Representation of Imaginary Numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

It seems to me that most math I have learnt (roughly up to precalculus) can be represented visually or geometrically. Calculus can give you areas under curves, algebra deals with conics, trigonometry deals with triangles etc.. For this reason I have always found it difficult to deal with imaginary numbers, as they would seem to imply the existence of a square with with negative area (the side length of a square is $\sqrt{A}$, and as $\sqrt{-1} = i \implies i^2 = -1 = A$). Thus in order to better understand imaginary numbers I was wondering if there are any geometric, visual or every-day-life representations of imaginary numbers that would satisfy my empirical brain?

Comment: Indeed! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_plane

Answer (score 2):

> This answer is a (somewhat challenging) invitation to read the section *Introduction* of the first chapter *Geometry and Complex Arithmetic* of T. Needham's book *[Visual Complex Analysis](http://static.ow.ly/docs/needham_t_visual_complex_analysis_bhj.pdf)*.
>
> The introductory section provides a motivation for the historical development of imaginary numbers (*Attention:* the meaning of *imaginary numbers* has been changed through times) together with some nice illustrations.

If this catches some interest you might skim through the whole book which is a guided tour through *Complex Analysis* with plenty of illuminating figures.